# Rust calling C, static const in C code

Tags: c, rust, bindgen

I have used rust-bindgen to generate rust interface code.

Now in the C code you can find this:

```
extern const struct mps_key_s _mps_key_ARGS_END;
#define MPS_KEY_ARGS_END (&_mps_key_ARGS_END)
```

Note that in the hole rest of the code `_mps_key_ARGS_END` does not appear again.

The macro MPS_KEY_ARGS_END gets used regularly amung other simular `mps_key_s`.

Now the code produced by rust-bindgen is this:

```
pub static _mps_key_ARGS_END: Struct_mps_key_s;
```

Now in C code here is a example usage:

```
extern void _mps_args_set_key(mps_arg_s args[MPS_ARGS_MAX], unsigned i,
                              mps_key_t key);

_mps_args_set_key(args, 0, MPS_KEY_ARGS_END);
```

In rust it looks like this:

```
pub fn _mps_args_set_key(args: [mps_arg_s, ..32u], i: ::libc::c_uint,
                         key: mps_key_t);
```

Now I try to call it like this:

```
_mps_args_set_key(args, 0 as u32, _mps_key_ARGS_END );
```

But I get a error:

> error: mismatched types: expected `*const Struct_mps_key_s`, found
>   `Struct_mps_key_s` (expected *-ptr, found enum Struct_mps_key_s)

I am not a good C programmer, and I dont even understand where these C static even get there values from.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

Update based on the answer of Chris Morgan.

I added this code (note, I replaced *const mps_key_s with mps_key_t):

```
pub static MPS_KEY_ARGS_END: mps_key_t = &_mps_key_ARGS_END;
```

Just for some extra information on why Im using `mps_key_t`, in C:

```
typedef const struct mps_key_s *mps_key_t;
```

In rust:

```
pub type mps_key_t = *const Struct_mps_key_s;
```

This seams seam to work better then befor but now Im getting a bad crash:

> error: internal compiler error: unexpected failure note: the compiler
>   hit an unexpected failure path. this is a bug. note: we would
>   appreciate a bug report:
>   http://doc.rust-lang.org/complement-bugreport.html note: run with
>   `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace task 'rustc' failed at 'expected
>   item, found foreign item _mps_key_ARGS_END::_mps_key_ARGS_END
>   (id=1102)',
>   /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libsyntax/ast_map/mod.rs:327

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a bug and should be reported as it directs.

Comment: Allreay did https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18360

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MPS_KEY_ARGS_END (&_mps_key_ARGS_END)
```

The `&` part indicates that it is taking a pointer to the object, that the type of `MPS_KEY_ARGS_END` will be `mps_key_s const*`. In Rust, that is `*const mps_key_s` (a raw pointer), and can be achieved in the same way as in C, `&_mps_key_ARGS_END`. You can define `MPS_KEY_ARGS_END` in a way that you can use conveniently like this:

```
static MPS_KEY_ARGS_END: *const mps_key_s = &_mps_key_ARGS_END;
```

Comment: @MatthieuM.: good point (I’m not used to working in C and forgot about that). Amended.